# Excel IF Function woth logical operators

Tags: excel, if-statement, logical-operators

I really don't know why this is not working, I want to create an additional column in excel with the following:

If the value X is lower or equal to 40, then 0, if between 41 and 55, then 1 and if greater 55, then 2.

I thought of this: =IF(x>41,0,IF(41<=x<=55,1,2)), but it does not work as it only gives me 0 and 2, but not 1...

Any idea here?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for an Excel IF statement is:
IF(condition, value if True, value if False)

You should write your statement like this:
IF(x>55,2,IF(x>40,1,0))

Answer (score 0):

On google sheets I was able to get the desired results with `=IF(x>41,IF(x>=55,2,1),0)`.  Your if statements appear to be backwards, and the double comparison statement is probably causing you to get false positives due to a partially true condition